# I can't get my fingerprint to work on my lenovo yoga 530-14ARR

Tags: 20.04, lenovo, fingerprint-reader

I just installed ubuntu 20.04.3, everything works just fine except my fingerprint reader, I don't think ubuntu recognize the reader because it doesn't show up. I am fairly new to Linux and don't really know where to begin to fix it.

Comment: On lenovo yoga c740 i had same issue.
I try lots of things I read. Newer make it work.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the terminal output of `sudo lsusb`? This will show hardware-specific details about your fingerprint reader. With this, compatibility can be checked 